# Can Gmail Notifier be used with a google apps email account?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, notifications

I would like to install Gmail notifier for my work email, which is not a gmail account, but runs in google apps.

I had this set up at a previous job in a similar situation (on OS X) but my first attempt failed here (on Windows 7).  I installed it, it would regularly as me to log in to my google account, but never notify me of incoming emails.

Is there a trick to this?

Comment: which gmail notifier are we referring to here?

Comment: @Chris probably the google one: https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/mihcahmgecmbnbcchbopgniflfhgnkff?hl=en

Comment: I think @FarmBoy is referring to Google's system tray tool: http://toolbar.google.com/gmail-helper/notifier_windows.html

Answer (score 1):

The standard Google desktop notifier is not compatible with Apps. This is rather confusing since it is sometimes advertised in the footer of an Apps Gmail account.

As others note, there's plenty of other options available, including Google Talk, browser plugins and third-party desktop notifiers.

Answer (score 0):

I use the [Firefox GMail Notifier](http://www.nexgenmedia.net/extensions/) add-on, and the [Windows Vista GMail Counter Gadget](http://gallery.live.com/liveItemDetail.aspx?li=41af0803-c761-465a-8a93-5c1da020e487&bt=1&pl=1) with multiple Gmail Apps accounts (I have a company and a family GMail Apps account, on different domains) with no problems.

Did you mean either of these?

Answer (score 0):

The Gmail Notifier 3rd party product is not compatible with Google Apps AFIK.  You can, however, install the Google Talk client which is compatible and will handle desktop notifications for email.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, but if I were you I'd just try another notifier, such as [Google Mail Checker Plus](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/gffjhibehnempbkeheiccaincokdjbfe?hl=en).

Answer (score 0):

At work, we have the Educational version of Google Apps.  It has single-sign on set up, so we don't know our real login and password.  We're also required to use IE 8 as our official browser on Windows XP at work.  I tried every notifier I could find and none was able to do the job within the limits of our work environment.  So, I wrote my own very basic notifier.  If anyone's in a similar situation, they might [find this helpful](http://www.distasis.com/cpp/gmail.htm).